# Netbeans gradle plugin runs from the incorrect working directory

Tags: java, netbeans, gradle, jetty, netbeans-8.1

Netbeans 8.1, Gradle 1.11, Gradle Support 1.3.1

By default running the gradle jettyRun using the plugin, executes from the Netbeans/bin directory and not the project directory.

This means that relative pathing is not working correctly. e.g.

```java
System.out.println(new File("").getAbsolutePath())
```

- gives `"C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0\bin"`
- instead of `"C:\Projects\MockServices"`

*Running from command line works correctly.*

### Console output

```
Executing: gradle jettyRun

Build file 'C:\E-Channels\Source\Bancs Connect\build.gradle': line 289
The TaskContainer.add() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please use the create() method instead.
C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0\bin
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
1 warning
:ProjectA:compileJava
:ProjectA:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:ProjectA:classes
...
```

*jettyRun fails to load project due to incorrect resolving of paths (jetty is booted, though)*

The question is: How do I get the working directory path right so that my config can remain unchanged? Until I can figure this out I have to start jetty via the command-line.

Comment: Does `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"))` give the same thing?  Note: `user.dir` property value is equivalent to CWD (current working directory)

Comment: I was being a bit stupid... we were using the system property to set the working directory for another IDE. Being gradle I could just use $projectDir variable to specify the "working directory". The problem still remains though... we have a native DLL in the working directory used by java